# How to boot Linux to command-line mode instead of GUI?

Tags: command-line, rhel, boot

I am using 32-bit Red Hat Linux in my VM. I want to boot it to command-line mode, not to GUI mode. I know that from there I can switch to GUI mode using `startx` command. How do I switch back to command-line mode?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update: The answer below is now obsolete**

For a lot of distros now, the default is systemd rather than sysvinit. The answer below was written with sysvinit in mind. The more-up-to-date answer (and the one you should use if you have systemd as your init system) is [golem's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184257/26909).

**sysvinit answer (obsolete on most current distros):**

You want to make runlevel 3 your default runlevel. From a terminal, switch to root and do the following:

```
[user@host]$ su
Password:
[root@host]# cp /etc/inittab /etc/inittab.bak #Make a backup copy of /etc/inittab
[root@host]# sed -i 's/id:5:initdefault:/id:3:initdefault:/' /etc/inittab #Make runlevel 3 your default runlevel
```

Anything after (and including) the second `#` on each line is a comment for you, you don't need to type it into the terminal.

See [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) on runlevels for more information.

**Explanation of `sed` command**

- The `sed` command is a stream editor (hence the name), you use it to manipulate streams of data, usually through [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
- Here, we're telling `sed` to replace the pattern `id:5:initdefault:` with the pattern `id:3:initdefault:` in the file `/etc/inittab`, which is the file that controls your runlevles. The general syntax for a `sed` search and replace is `s/pattern/replacement_pattern/`.
- The `-i` option tells `sed` to apply the modifications in place. If this were not present, `sed` would have outputted the resulting file (after substitution) to the terminal (more generally to standard output).

**Update**

To switch back to text mode, simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This will not stop your graphical session, it will simply switch you back to the terminal you logged in at. You can switch back to the graphical session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, when I switch to GUI using `startx` how can I switch back to command line?

Comment: @0xF1 Answer updated. Please see if this helps.

Comment: @0xF1 Added an explanation for the `sed` command.

Comment: I would generally advise against using `sed` on configuration files, unless you know exactly what you are doing. The line in question might be also a comment and yet would still be changed. Hence the regular expression should be more precise, at least require the string `id:...` to be at the beginning of the line. Since the man page doesn't say anything about how white spaces are treated, you probably want to use `s/^ *id:5:initdefault:` (which doesn't include `Tab` character, by the way).

Comment: @peterph Agreed; my MO is to usually do such edits _in situ_. I'm using `sed` here for 2 reasons: a)spare myself the extra explanation of switching to root with environment so as to fire up a graphical editor. b) get the OP interested in `sed`.

Comment: I usually use a light-weight tty-based emacslike editor for root-owned files.  `sudo jed /etc/inittab`.  I don't want to run GUI anything as root.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, at least on my current OS. Take a look at @golem's answer below. That worked for me. I'm using fedora 27.

Comment: @Lance Very good point. Thanks for the notice. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 33):

Update for RedHat/CentOS 7 that has switched from sysvinit to systemd.

To switch from GUI to CLI: `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`

To switch from CLI to GUI: `systemctl isolate graphical.target`

To set the CLI as a default *runlevel* (*target* in systemd terminology): `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`. Analogously for GUI: `systemctl set-default graphical.target`

*CLI = Command Line Interface = command-line mode

Comment: Also see: [Related Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets-Change_Default).

Comment: Thank you.. Every forum is still dumping the old knowledge about /etc/inittab even though its obsolete.

Answer (score 11):

First switch user to root.

```
su -
Password:
```

Enter root password.

Use your favorite editor to modify this line in `/etc/inittab`:

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

Change the 5 to 3.  When you (re)boot the computer it will take you to the command line rather than to the GUI.

Comment: Please include instructions about how the OP should do this as root and to which file. This answer, as it stands, is not fit to help someone who's new to Linux.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my oversight.  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Does this mean that the GUI is not running, or is it hidden?

Comment: @AaronFranke For Redhat systems in run level 3 the GUI is not enabled (or turned off in the case of a system which was switched from runlevel 5 to 3 without a reboot).

Answer (score 4):

On a side note, if you've already booted into graphical mode and would like to switch to text mode, you could just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and back again to graphical mode by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Linux has by default 6 text terminals and 1 graphical terminal. You can switch between these terminals by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd>. Replace `n` with 1-7. <kbd>F7</kbd> would take you to graphical mode only if it booted into run level 5 or you have started X using `startx` command; otherwise, it will just show a blank screen on <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: show this work in RHEL 7?

Comment: Just saw your comment.  My apologies, my answer shows my naivete and limited experience.  Needless to say, in RHEL 7 there's no `startx` (this script exists in Slackware Linux).  In _systemd_ systems (which is almost all major LInux distributions these days), `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` boots the OS into CLI persistently.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from changing `/etc/inittab`, you can also tell the kernel on its command line what target runlevel should be passed to `init` once it is started. This is done by simply appending the desired runlevel to the command line (it has to be the last argument I believe).

You can do this either as a one-off thing during boot, provided your bootloader allows you to change the kernel command line, or you can duplicate entry in the bootloader configuration and pick the right one when booting (useful when you are booting into various runlevels often).

For systems using `systemd` the process is similar, but means more typing since the magic string appended to the kernel command line is in the form of `systemd.unit=desired.target`.

As for `startx`, it can also start additional sessions by giving it an unused X display number (numbering starts from 0): `startx -- :1` will start X server on display :1, locating it at the first unused VT (often VT8, since first 6 are usually Linux consoles and 7 is used by the first running X session). Note that the X server usually needs root privileges so you either have to do this as `root` (which is not a good idea), or the binary has to be setuid root (the need for this is normally removed by using a display manager).

Comment: +1 Great answer. Not very newbie friendly, though.

Comment: Yes, changing `inittab` makes much more sense, since one usually wants to bring up the system to the same state all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Even being a quite old thread, may be useful.
On system using **`systemd`**, */etc/inittab* is no longer in use. The method is quite simple:

**Terminal mode**

```
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

**Graphic Mode**

```
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target  /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, for the case where you want/need to change the setting when the system isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

After replace the default runlevel to `id:3:initdefault:` in `/etc/inittab` using your preferred text editor (as said previously), it's very important check if there's some plymouth (splash screen) installed in your system. In this case, will be need to remove the installation of it, or just remove the splash keyword from you /boot/grub/grub.cfg using your preferred text editor (vim, pico, or others).
To remove plymouth:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge plymouth
```

Edit your grub.cfg:

```
sudo vim /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Finally, upgrade the grub configuration:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

In next boot, you'll have just text mode login screen. That's it.

Enjoy Linux box!

Answer (score -1):

The oracle-linux 7 installation by defaults takes minimal installation option . You must change it to installation with GUI mode at the time of installation .This has solved my issue on not able to use the graphical user mode .

Comment: It seems you have the OP's request backwards. The OP appears to be struggling to get to the CLI, not to the GUI.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried systemctl, update-rc.d and even editing the GRUB config, but nothing worked. Then I commented out the default display manager in /etc/X11/default-display-manager, rebooted and finally: the terminal!!!! It's as simple as that!

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

and reboot the VM. The VM will get into CLI mode.