# CentOS boot without GUI has actually started gui before login

Tags: centos, command-line, boot, gui

I have read [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184257/115506) to a post, it suggest to use:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

to log in command line mode. It works fine, except before login, it seems CentOS has boot into the graphical mode which make the start up process quite slow. See the following picture:
[image]

I have minimal installed CentOS before, it boot much faster compare to my situation now. So what's the reason for this, and how to get rid of the pre-boot gui?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of the pre-boot GUI you have to remove the `rhgb` option in the `grub` options. If you also want the kernel messages during boot, you also have to remove the `quite` option of the kernel append line.

To do so, edit the file `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor of your choice and adopt the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`.

If you just want to remove the pre-boot GUI it would look as follows.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet"
```

If you also want the kernel messages during boot, just set it as f

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

You also might want to preserve the default entry in the file and to do so you just comment that line with `#`.

After you have edited the file you have to generate the `grub` configuration as follows.

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-list/2004-May/msg07775.html this explains what rhgb does.